# Why can't websites access JRE in Yosemite?

Tags: safari, java, macos

Please see the attached image which shows an error/information message I am seeing regularly since upgrading to Yosemite. I don't know which website is asking for Java, as there is a different site showing in Safari each time I see it, but I do know that I am using the latest version of JRE so it's not clear why this message is being shown.

Can someone please advise me the best way to check what process is generating this, and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: So you clicked OK and installed the software from the Apple website that then appeared, and you are still seeing this message appear?

Comment: Clicking 'OK' just dismissed the dialog. The 'More Info…' button took me to the Java download page, from where I downloaded and installed the latest version. And, as you say, I am still seeing the message appear, seemingly at random.

Comment: How did you install the JRE? and did you do that before upgrading to Yosemite?

Comment: I installed it by downloading and running the DMG version of the 'Mac OS X x64' link on this page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html and this was done after upgrading to Yosemite.

Comment: Have you ever installed the Facebook VideoChat app?  That could generating the message. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1757743#21

Comment: @Moto_Nomad thanks - that seems to be the issue; I've uninstalled the service and will wait to see what happens. If it works (i.e. I stop seeing the message above), I'll answer this question with the steps to take so people don't have to refer to another forum. Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart your browser after installing the JRE?

Comment: @patrix Yes, more than once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Moto_Nomad, this appears to have been caused by the Facebook Video Chat plugin requesting Java Runtime Environment. I needed to undertake the following steps to locate and disable this process.

Launch Terminal, and type the command `launchctl list | grep facebook`

This results in something like the following:

```
-   1   com.facebook.videochat.<yourname>.updater
-   0   com.apple.facebook.xpc
```

Where `<yourname>` is your Facebook id. To delete the process, type the following command:

`launchctl remove com.facebook.videochat.<yourname>.updater`

Remember to replace `<yourname>` with the Facebook ID returned in the first step. To check the command has worked, type `launchctl list | grep facebook` again. This time you should see the following:

```
-   0   com.apple.facebook.xpc
```

Having done this myself I can confirm that the dialog shown in the question is no longer appearing.

Comment: Update: it appears to be reinstalled every time I restart unfortunately, meaning the error message starts appearing again. I know this is probably another question, but if I do find a way to stop this happening I'll add more information to this answer

Comment: launchctl -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.facebook.videochat.uklennugtag.plist
Unrecognized subcommand: -w Who knows the correct subcommand?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Facebook video chat plugin permanently by following the steps at http://ilearncocoa.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-uninstall-facebook-video-calling.html

Answer (score 0):

Error appears to be fixed by installing Java 6.

http://fredericiana.com/2014/10/21/osx-yosemite-java-runtime-environment/